# Views in Drupal 8 / Preprocess Function

Tags: function, drupal, view, drupal-8, drupal-theming

I've a question about Drupal 8, again and again and again...

Today, I've two views displayed on my front page and this two views display two differents informations types (in the first : Last articles in a caroussel, in the second : Recents events like a calendar with date and little description).

So, I would like to know if it's possible to template those views differently (two types) ?

Template those with preprocess functions ?

Or

Template those with templates files and template each field of those views ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your template is not complex, you can simply add in your views a field of type Custom text.
In there you can write HTML, use your fields (replacement patterns) and even use twig for custom logic.

[image]

*Make sure you have all the fields you need hidden.
*Make sure the field "Global: Custom text" is the last field in the list.

Another way is to create a theme by following the naming convention (see the docs [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x)

Comment: Ok Thanks, that a simple way ;-), It's not possible with preprocess functions for a complete theme ?